# BroadcastReceiver declared in Android Manifest, App force closing.

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I keep getting Force close error while testing this app. App opening fine.. but after 3-4 seconds force close error dialog box coming up. code included.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cy.headset"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".Main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.cy.headset.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Java Code**

```
package com.cy.headset;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Main extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Headphone connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}}
```

**XML UI file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Comment: you are using same name for `Activity` and `BroadcastReceiver` class's. change one to any other name or if `BroadcastReceiver` is another package then use full name including package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the package of your BroadcastReceiver class which is Main.java?

```
<receiver android:name=".Main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It should not com.cy.headset right? Since it will be a conflict with your main activity which is Main.java

I think there are two solutions on this one specify the package of your receiver in the manifest.

example:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.name.Main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or if you want your receiver to be at the same package of your main activity which is Main.java rename your receiver

example:

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryChange" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity
    android:name="com.cy.headset.Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Another way to do it is.

```
<receiver android:name="com.cy.headset.BatteryChange" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity
    android:name="com.cy.headset.Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare both your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and your [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to be `com.cy.headset.Main`. This is not going to work.

When your app is installed, Android tries to launch an Activity called `Main`, but finds a BroadcastReceiver instead.

Separate these into two different classes, one extending Activity and one extending BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name=".Main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity
    android:name="com.cy.headset.MainActivity" <<Change it to MainActivity
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You have defined the Receiver and activity name same and both are in same package **com.cy.headset** so rename either one or either define in different package and give fully qualified package name.

For ex: If receiver is in **com.cv.headset.receiver** then write in manifest like

```
<receiver android:name="com.cv.headset.receiver.Main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```